# calls to model in Codeigniter Constructor... how to

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am developing a CRM for our agency in Codeigniter and I have a question that I can't seem to find a solid answer on. If I have a task that I do on the majority of methods in a controller, is there any way to define that action only once? For instance...

Every view call gets passed the $data variable, like so...

```
$this->load->view('templates/template.php', $data);
```

So if I am doing something like getting the admins information in every function of the controller, how can i tell it to do that action ONE time and pass it to all my functions.

Like this...

```
$data['admin'] = $this->Crm_model->get_admin();
```

I've tried putting that ^ in the constructor and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```
$data['admin'] = $this->Crm_model->get_admin();
```

in the constructor, `$data`'s scope is limited to the constructor. You need to create it as a class property so it is scoped to the entire class. Do this instead

```
$this->data['admin'] = $this->Crm_model->get_admin();
```

in the constructor, and then in other methods, you can access the array by doing `$this->data`

Here's an example:

```
class Foobar extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->data['foo'] = "bar";
    }

    public function index() {
        // use the class property data here to add more info to it
        $this->data['hello'] = "world";

        // now pass this to the view
        $this->load->view('myView', $this->data);
        // myView will receive both $foo and $hello

    }
}
```

Comment: ok so essentially theres no way then of that one $data variable being passed to the view to be a combination of variables both within and outside the function, but within the same class? Correct?

Comment: You should be able to do that. Hold up while I put together an example.

Comment: Ah I gotcha, yeah that'll work perfectly. Thanks for the help man.